# How to open script in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, adsense

So when a user interacts with `<script>`
, I want to make it open in a new tab.

I tried doing this:

```
<script target="_blank"
```

but that didn't work. Help please!

EDIT: I'm sorry for not making myself that clear. I meant that when a user clicks on my bidvertiser ads, I want the ads to open on a new page. they are in script form so when the user clicks on the script, I want to open the script in a new page sort of like `<a target="_blank>`

Comment: Why would you want to open it in new tab?

Comment: You want to open a new tab with script? or you want to open a tab with a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this is exactly what your looking for. But by the way you said the following:

> "when a user interacts with script , I want to make it open in a new tab"

I assume you mean when the script is executed "after html page is rendered" you want a new tab to be created, if so then this code will work both inline with your html or in its own script file.

```
//pure js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
   window.open('http://www.google.com');
});

// jquery
$(function() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com');
});
```

++++++++

Per your latest reply.

You could setup a click listener for the ads, i'd suggest maybe using a shared css class amongst the ads and in JQuery setup a click listener like such. Maybe using 'Inspect Element' you can find a class name that each ads has and use the code below to listen to the click.

```
$('.class-name').click(function () { 
    window.open('http://www.theurlfromad'); 
});
```

Comment: @ValveRewards you need to setup a click listener for the ad's, maybe by using Jquery to add listener via the class name. See above for the code.

Comment: @ValveRewards what kind of ad's are these? Are they injected into the page via a script you've included in the html? We might be able to figure out a way if we know the source of the ad script.